# What are the important texts of Gaudiya Vaishnavism?

Tags: scripture, gaudiya-vaishnavism

I want to study Gaudiya Vaishnavism in deep. So I want to know the principal texts of Gaudiya Vaishnavism. I already know Bhagavatam enjoys great prominence. Here I am asking about texts by acharyas which are written to establish the school. I am interested in knowing the works written till 18th century only.

Providing an English translation or Hindi translation or both translations is appreciated.

Comment: Why till 18th century only? Baladeva's books such as a commentary on Vedanta sutra and all  other his books I think were written in the 18th century.

Comment: i didn't exclude him. thats why i wrote till 18th century, I need his books s well.

Comment: It is subjective which is better . What's the problem in studying deep? I like Krishna. @Wikash_hindu

Comment: I do think that the Gaudiya Vaishnavism consists of conflicting truths and conveniently leaving out some important scriptures but if you like Krishna go for it. @Krishna Varna

Comment: @Wikash_hindu they don't leave out scriptures. They explain in different way. Can you cite example where they conveniently left out? And other sects don't leave out...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will post what I consider key books. I am limiting to very few though it is not that others are less important. For some of the books I didn't give English links, because free online versions are not available for the whole book. Such books can be bought online if need be.

1.Bhagavata Sandarbha also known as Sat Sandarbhas: (Jiva Goswami)

The first four Sandarbhas deal primarily with sambandha-jñAna, that is, knowledge of God, the living entities, the world, and the relationships between
them. The Bhakti-sandarbha covers abhidheya, or the means of reviving the
personal relationship between the living entity and Bhagavan, while the final
book, Priti-sandarbha, describes prayojana, the ultimate perfected state of
pure love for Krishna.

The first three Sandarbhas address questions of ontology in a relatively
non-sectarian way, using criteria of knowledge and proof-texts that would
be acceptable to an audience much broader than the followers of Caitanya.
Only when major issues regarding the status of the world, the personal
nature of divinity, and the individuality of the jiva have been settled does
Jiva Gosvami go on (in the Krishna-sandarbha) to identify that divinity with
Krishna and describe his unique characteristics, relying on scriptural sources
that are more internal to the tradition. This is interesting, for it means that
Jiva exhaustively describes Bhagavan without seriously describing Krishna;
that he explains the concept of lilA without addressing rasa; and that he
establishes the status of the internal energy (antarangA sakti) without mentioning
Sri Radha. Of course, in the process of elaborating the qualities and
characteristics of Bhagavan, Jiva broadly identifies him with Vishnu/Krishna,
but this is an assumption that many Vedantic writers will make, if only for
the sake of demonstrating the applicability of general principles. Vishnu/
Krishna is present throughout the first three Sandarbhas, but not in the way
Caitanya Vaishnavas know him.

a. Translation by HH Bhanu Swami(English)

[Tattva-sandarbha](https://archive.org/details/1TattvaSandarbhaTrans.ByBhanuSwami)

[Bhagavat-sandarbha](https://archive.org/details/2BhagavatSandarbhaBhanuSwami)

[Paramatma-sandarbha](https://archive.org/details/3ParamatmaSandarbhaBhanuSwami)

[Krishna-sandarbha](https://archive.org/details/4KrsnaSandarbhaBhanuSwami)

[Bhakti-sandarbha](https://archive.org/details/5BhaktiSandarbhaBhanuSwami)

[Priti-sandarbha](https://archive.org/details/6PritiSandarbhaBhanuSwami)

With commentary of Baladeva Vidyabhusna on Tattva Sandarbha and auto commentary by Jiva Goswami on first 4 sandarbhas

b. Translation by Haridasa Shastri (Hindi)

[Tattva-sandarbha](https://archive.org/details/tattva_sandarbha)

[Bhagavat-sandarbha](https://archive.org/details/bhagavat_sandarbha)

[Paramatma-sandarbha](https://archive.org/details/paramatma_sandarbha)

[Krishna-sandarbha](https://archive.org/details/krishna_sandarbha)

[Bhakti-sandarbha](https://archive.org/details/bhakti_sandarbha)

[Priti-sandarbha](https://archive.org/details/priti_sandarbha)

2.[Brihad Bhagavatmrita of Sanatana Goswami:(English)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brihad-bhagavatamrita)

3.Laghu Bhagavatamrita of Rupa Goswami:

[Hindi(with commentary of Baladeva Vidyabhusana)](https://archive.org/details/LaghuBhagavatamrta.VenkatesvarPress) and [English](http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Rupa/Rupa_Goswami_Sri_Laghu_Bhagavatamrta.pdf)

4.[Bhakti Rasamrita Sindhu of Rupa Goswami: English](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/sri-bhakti-rasamrta-sindhu)

5.Hari Bhakti Vilasa of Sanatana Goswami(Hindi), Translated by Hari dasa Shastri
[Volume 1](https://archive.org/details/hbv_vol1) and 
[Volume 2](https://archive.org/details/hbv_vol2)

6.Gayatri Bhasya of Jiva Goswami with expanded commenatary by the translator Haridasa Shastri in [Hindi](https://archive.org/details/gayatrivyakhyavivrtih)

7.Brahma Sutra bhasya (Baladeva Vidyabhusana)

a. Govinda Bhasya translated by Srisa Chandra Vasu Vidyarnava [English](https://archive.org/stream/Sacred_Books_of_the_Hindus/SBH%2005%20-%20Vedantasutras%20of%20Badarayana%20with%20Baladevabhashya%20English%20Translation%20-%20Srisa%20Chandra%20Vasu%201934#page/n7/mode/2up)

b. Govinda Bhasya translated by Kushakrita dasa [English](http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Baladeva-Vidyabhusana/Baladeva_Vidyabhusana_Sri_Vedanta-sutra.pdf)

c. Brahma Sutra Karika Bhasya translated by Dr.Demian Martins [English](https://archive.org/details/BrahmaSutraKarikaBhasyam)

d.Govinda Bhasya translated by Krsnadasa Baba [Hindi](https://archive.org/details/GovindaBhasya.KrsnadasBaba)

8.Bhagavad Gita bhasya :

a. Saratha Varshini Tika (Vishwanath Chakravarthy Thakur)

Translation by HH BHanu Swami [English](https://archive.org/details/BhagavadGitaSararthaVarsiniTikaByVishvanathaCakravartiThakura)

b. Gita Bhusana (Baladeva Vidyabhusana)

Translation by HH BHanu Swami [English](https://archive.org/details/BhagavadGitaGitaBhushanaByBaladevaVidyabhushana)

9.Ishopanishad Bhasya of Baladeva Vidyabhusana:

[Hindi](https://archive.org/details/Isopanisad.KrsnadasBaba) and 
[English(can only be read)](https://www.scribd.com/document/6130855/Isopanisad)

10.VishnuSahasraNama Bhasya of Baladeva Vidyabhusana:

[Hindi](https://archive.org/details/VisnuSahasraNama.KrsnadasBaba/page/n47)
[English](http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Baladeva-Vidyabhusana/Baladeva_Vidyabhusana_Vishnu_Sahasra_Nama.pdf)

11.Siddhanata Darpana of Baladeva Vidyabhusana:

It is about controversies around Bhagavatam. Starting from saying it is authored by Vopadeva, not one of the 18 puranas, etc...

[Hindi](https://archive.org/details/SiddhantaDarpanaOfSriBaladevaVidyabhushana)

12.Gopala Champu of Jiva Goswami translated by Shri Vanamali Das Shastri [in Hindi)](https://archive.org/details/gopala_champu)

The Gopala-campu narrates the pastimes as found in the Srimad-bhagavatham with the addition of rasa. It describes the pastimes of Krsna from his appearance until his return to Vraja.

13.Ananda Vrindavan Champu of Kavi Karnapur translated by Shri Vanamali Das Shastri [in Hindi](https://archive.org/details/ananda_vrindavana_champu/page/n13)

This book elaborately follows Srimad Bhagavatam to describe Krishna playing with calves and stealing butter, frolicking with the cows and cowherd boys, and finally His sweet intimate pastimes with Sri Radha and the Vraja gopis, with many details and pastimes in between.

14.Sarartha Darshini, commentary on Srimad Bhagavatam by Vishwanath Chakravarthy Thakur [English](https://archive.org/search.php?query=creator%3A%22Vedantist%22&and[]=subject%3A%22Srila+Vishvanatha+Cakravarti+Thakura%22)
Translated by HH Bhanu Swami

15.Chaitanya Hagiographies:

a. Chaitanya Bhagavata in English(with commentary of Bhakti Siddhanta Sarasvati Thakur) 
[Adi khanda](https://archive.org/details/CBAdi_201901) 
[Madhya khanda](https://archive.org/details/CBMadhya) 
[Antya khanda](https://archive.org/details/CBAntya)

[Chaitanya Bhagavata Hindi](https://archive.org/details/HindiBookShriChaitanyaBhagwat)

b. Chaitanya Charitamrita [with commentary of Srila Prabhupada](https://archive.org/details/SriCaitanyaaritamrta1975Complete/page/n1)

Answer (score 5):

Apart from the Srimad-Bhagavatam the key Gaudiya Vaishnava texts are:

• *Chaitanya Charitamrita* by Krishnadasa Kaviraj. You can buy it here in nine volumes (along with the commentary of A.C. Bhaktivedanta Swami Prabhupada) [**here**](https://www.amazon.in/Sri-Caitanya-Caritamrita-Pastimes-Mahaprabhu/dp/0947259066).

• *Chaitanya Bhagavatam* by Vrindavana Dasa. You can read it [**here**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Vrindavana-dasa-Thakura/Vrindavana_dasa_Thakura_Sri_Caitanya_Bhagavata2.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiI066HlKXhAhUP7HMBHf7eCGgQFjADegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw05gJnY5ELBqKNKJrP4lXEm&cshid=1553787122656).

• *Chaitanya Mangala* by Lochana Dasa. You can read it [**here**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.krishnapath.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Caitanya-mangala.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiN8fKalKXhAhXVheYKHdkOBAEQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw0oGgj5cyGfMxy7YgRFpfZO&cshid=1553787207539).

• *Sri Krishna Chaitanya Charitra Mahakavyam* by Murari Gupta. You can read it [**here**](http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Murari-Gupta/Murari_Gupta_Sri_Krsna_Caitanya_Carita_Maha_Kavya.pdf).

• *Brahma-Samhita*. You can read it here with the commentary of Jiva Goswami [**here**](http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Jiva/Jiva_Goswami_Brahma_Samhita_Commentary.pdf).

• *Kali-Santarana Upanishad*. You can read it [**here**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/kali-santarana-upanishad-of-shukla-yajurveda/d/doc217041.html).

• *Sarartha Varsini Tika*, Vishvanatha Chakrabarti Thakura's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can read it in English [**here**](https://archive.org/download/BhagavadGitaSararthaVarsiniTikaByVishvanathaCakravartiThakura/Bhagavad-Gita%20Sarartha-Varsini-Tika%20by%20Vishvanatha%20Cakravarti%20Thakura.pdf).

• *Gita Bhusana*, Baladeva Vidyabhusana's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can read it in English [**here**](https://archive.org/download/BhagavadGitaGitaBhushanaByBaladevaVidyabhushana/Bhagavad-Gita%20Gita-Bhushana%20by%20Baladeva%20Vidyabhushana.pdf).

• *Sattvata Tantra*. You can read it [**here**](https://archive.org/download/SriSatvataTantraEnglishTranslation_201804/Sri-Satvata-Tantra-English-Translation.pdf).

• *Prameya Ratnavali* by Baladeva Vidyabhusana. You can read it [**here**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Baladeva-Vidyabhusana/Baladeva_Vidyabhusana_Prameya_Ratnavali.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjj-aHmlqXhAhV1guYKHW0xAzsQFjABegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw3LczgGqBs_kogKuTQqEl2p).

• *Bhakti-rasamrta-sindhu* by Rupa Goswami. You can read it [**here**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Rupa/Rupa_Goswami_Bhakti_rasamrta_sindhu.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjBxO6BjKXhAhUO3o8KHVD7B-4QFjACegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw3JeNbfikBXISGPAt2CIU9J&cshid=1553784970666).

• *Ujjvala-nilamani* by Rupa Goswami. You can read it [**here**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Rupa/Rupa_Goswami_Sri_Ujjvala_Nilamani.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiCgsKljKXhAhUIRo8KHQzEDk4QFjADegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw2kcbE4Oms5J8Ly7l2tLatL).

• *Upadesamrta* by Rupa Goswami. You can read it [**here**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://gosai.com/sites/gosai/files/books/upadesamrta.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj2r5bfjKXhAhVEinAKHSmeC6kQFjACegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw3jazpgH6HqpxqQ5qUW6Iw4).

• *Brhat-bhagavatamrta* by Sanatana Goswami. You can read it [**here**](http://ebooks.iskcondesiretree.com/pdf/Gaudiya_Books%20/Sanatana_Goswami/Sanatana_Goswami_Sri_Brhad_Bhagavatamrta.pdf).

• *Hari-bhakti-vilasa* by Sanatana Goswami. You can read it [**here**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Sanatana/Sanatana_Goswami_Hari_Bhakti_vilasa_full.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjomYzAjqXhAhXL6Y8KHe5hBD4QFjABegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw3yk2HzndGUcTV_255T2WUu).

• *Aisvarya Kadambini* by Baladeva Vidyabhusana. You can read it [**here**](http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Baladeva-Vidyabhusana/Baladeva_Vidyabhusana_Aisvarya_Kadambini.pdf).

• *Vedanta Syamantaka* by Baladeva Vidyabhusana. You can read it [**here**](http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Baladeva-Vidyabhusana/Baladeva_Vidyabhusana_Sri_Vedanta_Syamantaka.pdf).

• *Govinda Bhashya*, a Gaudiya commentary on the Brahma Sutras, by Baladeva Vidyabhusana. You can read it [**here**](http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Baladeva-Vidyabhusana/Baladeva_Vidyabhusana_Sri_Vedanta-sutra.pdf).

• *Sat Sandarbhas* by Jiva Goswami:

1) *Tattva Sandarbha*. You can read it [**here**](http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Jiva/Jiva_Goswami_Sri_Tattva_Sandarbha.pdf).

2) *Bhagavata Sandarbha*. You can read it [**here**](http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Jiva/Jiva_Goswami_Sri_Bhagavat_Sandarbha.pdf).

3) *Paramatma Sandarbha*. You can read it [**here**](http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Jiva/Jiva_Goswami_Sri_Paramatma_Sandarbha.pdf).

4) *Krishna Sandarbha*. You can read it [**here**](http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Jiva/Jiva_Goswami_Sri_Krishna_Sandarbha.pdf).

5) *Bhakti Sandarbha*. You can read it [**here**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://vedicilluminations.com/downloads/Acharya%2520Books/Jiva%2520Goswami%2520Sri%2520Bhakti%2520Sandarbha.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiqnNitkKXhAhXKvo8KHfCQCSIQFjABegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw3I7BA8Gse3TOV6o_16vJ9_).

6) *Priti Sandarbha*. You can read it [**here**](http://www.krishnapath.org/Library/Goswami-books/Jiva/Jiva_Goswami_Sri_Priti_Sandarbha.pdf).

All works given above are in English.

Comment: What about garga samhita and Vasudeva Upanishad? I guess these two also.

Comment: Which Gaudiya Vaishnava Acharya quotes Vasudeva Upanishad? And do you know any English translation of Garga Samhita? @KrishnaShweta

Comment: I dont know anything about vasudeva upanishad. I read it here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17099/6981 .

Comment: Garga samhita is here http://wikikrishna.com/index.php?title=Garga_Samhita

Comment: @KrishnaShweta I think early Gaudiya Vaishnava acaryas did not quote from the Garga Samhita. And Jiva Gosvami has quoted from the Vasudeva Upanishad in his Sandarbhas, see at https://www.harekrsna.com/sun/features/06-08/features1033.htm But those two are not considered to be the principal texts of Gaudiya Vaishnavism which is asked about in the question.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa Oh ok. Thank you.

Comment: I think Kalisantarana Upanishad was not quoted by the early Gaudiya Vaishnava authors, and thus it is not considered to be the principal text of Gaudiya Vaishnavism.